# Sublime Text 3 SublimeLinter plugin not able to find jshint

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

For some reason, SublimeLinter3, or the SublimeLinter3 JSHint linter plugin, seems unable to parse the `PATH` environment variable and is thus unable to run `jshint`:

```
SublimeLinter: Could not parse shell PATH output:
<empty> 
error: SublimeLinter could not determine your shell PATH. It is unlikely that any linters  will work. 

Please see the troubleshooting guide for info on how to debug PATH problems.
SublimeLinter: WARNING: jshint deactivated, cannot locate 'jshint' 
Can't connect
Unable to fetch update url contents
```

The `jshint` binary is in the `PATH`, however:

```
$ which jshint
/home/path/to/bin/jshint
```

The problem only occurs on Ubuntu. Works flawlessly on OS X. I've scoured through the [official docs](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting.html) to no avail.

Using `bash` if that's of any consequence.

Comment: I experience exact same issue on OS X (El Capitan) with `oh-my-zsh` installed. Not an issue with the default bash shell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I eventually fixed this by opening up the SublimeLinter preferences and manually adding the path to the linter:

```
"paths": {
    "linux": ["/path/to/jshint/bin"],
    "osx": [],
    "windows": []
},
```

If you don't already have it, you can install via `npm`:

```
npm install -g jshint
```

And you find its location with:

```
which jshint
```

or in Windows:

```
where jshint
```

Comment: A **Windows** example which worked for me was: `"paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": ["C:/Users/myUserName/AppData/Roaming/npm"]
        }`

Comment: How did you open SublimeLinter's preferences?

Comment: @Imray `Preferences > Package Settings > Sublime Linter > Settings - User`

Comment: When I copy that in, I get an error `Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters 1:8`

Comment: @Imray Copy *what* in exactly? Did you forget the trailing `,` at the end of the line?

Comment: @Imray If your file is empty when you first open it, copy the entire contents of SublimeLinter's `Settings - Default` file first, then edit the affected rows.

Comment: @jorum But in `Settings - Default` there's no `"paths:"`

Answer (score 6):

This fix is specific to windows, you could edit your preferences like jorum. OR you can add it to your windows "Path" which may be more helpful in the future.

Start > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables...

**Select your PATH and click edit.**

ADD this to the end of the Variable Value: 
     `;C:\Users\YOURUSERNAMEHERE\node_modules\jshint\bin`

TO TEST: Open a command prompt and type 
     `jshint -v`
and you should get a version number and not an error.

What you just did was added told your OS where it can find jshint, your install location may be different, in that case just search for a jshint folder on your system that has a /bin folder inside it and link there instead. NOTE the semi-colon(;) at the beginning separates different PATH's so be sure its included.

Comment: Thank you for including an answer for windows users :)

Comment: My Windows 7 machine needed the path `C:/Users/myUserName/AppData/Roaming/npm` instead. You can find the right path for your system by seaching your User folder for `jshint.cmd`.